# What is a "reverse controller" in the Play! framework?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

What is a "reverse controller" in Play! 2.0? I've read the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaRouting), but I'm still struggling to understand it.

I'm specifically trying to understand the difference between `controllers.routes.MyController` and `controllers.routes.ref.MyController`. When should I use each one? (I'm using Java.)

Comment: I have only worked in scala with Play for now but from my point of view, you should always use the first notation : `controllers.routes.MyController`.

Answer (score 4):

The normal controller handles a HTTP request as defined in the file `routes`. The reverse controller can prepare the URL that would trigger the request.

You should use the reverse controller computed URLs instead of hard coded urls in the `href` attributes of your links, in the `src` attributes of your java scripts and in your test cases. etc. Whenever you need a link from your application back to your application, consider using the reverse controller instead of hard coding the URL.

This is useful when you later change the route to your controller, you don't have to change all the URLs in the HTML files or in the tests.

Comment: Please see the second part of the question. When should I use the "ref" version vs. the normal one?

Comment: Hi Jacob, you can use the normal one to process a request. The reverse is just to generate the URL for a request. Typically in your code you would program the normal controllers and let the framework to call them. For the reverse controllers the situation is mirrored: the framework provides the reverse controllers and you would call them to create an URL.